# Resizing an image in gimp

Tags: images, gimp

In gimp I imported two separate images as separate layers into an image. I'm trying to resize one of these images so that it better matches the other. How can I do this?

I tried right clicking on the image, and selecting "scale," but it just scales the whole image, not just the one image that I'm trying to change.

I tried the scale tool. As I change the size of the image it gives a preview of what the size of the new image. But when I click the button to make the changes, it seems to do it, but in the end the image is still there, unchanged.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Select the Layer you want to scale. In your Layer selection dialog.
2. In the menu bar of the main window select `Layer` or press `Alt+L`
3. Go down to `Scale Layer...` or press `S`
4. Happy scaling

Hope this is what you wanted.